# add vertical line of the mean to density plot

Tags: r, density-plot

Following the example from this [website](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html), we can generate a density plot for several factors within a `data.frame`

```
library(sm)
attach(mtcars)
sm.density.compare(mpg, cyl, xlab="Miles Per Gallon")
```

My question is very simple, how can be add a vertical line for each factor which represents the **median** or the **mean**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example for the **mean**. To calculate the **median**, simply replace "FUN = mean" with "FUN = median" in the aggregate function.

```
library(sm)
attach(mtcars)
sm.density.compare(mpg, cyl, xlab="Miles Per Gallon")

means <- aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, FUN = mean)
abline(v = means[1,2], col = 2)
abline(v = means[2,2], col = 3, lty = 2)
abline(v = means[3,2], col = 4, lty = 3)
```

[image: Desired Plot]